# How to model a header detail requirement when header has values that cannot be apportioned to details?

Tags: powerbi, dimensional-modeling, star-schema

I have a header-detail type of a requirement.

For example:

My dimensions are product, customer, DateTable

My fact table is FactOrders (columns: order num, prod_id, cust_id, date, num of items, total amount, cost of pkg).

This is a star schema.

There is a new requirement to add/show data for order line items, and to make a drill through such that when user clicks on an order they should be able to drill through to a new page showing the order lines.

Now I'm thinking about this requirement in terms of data modelling. Getting rid of the FactOrders, and just have FactOrderLines doesn't look like a solution due to the presence of cost of pkg because this is an order level value and cannot be apportioned to order lines.

2 solutions come to my mind:

1. Create FactOrderLines and connect it to FactOrders. But this will make the model a snowflake.
2. Another option is to create a new dimension that has the distinct order numbers, and treat this as a dimension table, then create FactOrderLines. Then, connect this dim table to FactOrderLines and FactOrders. Thus I retain the star schema by not having relation between FactOrders and FactOrderLines, yet I can achieve the drill through behaviour in OrderNum.

What is the recommended pattern for such a requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Italians, merging the header into your existing fact table and keeping just a single fact table is the way to go.

https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/header-detail-vs-star-schema-models-in-tabular-and-power-bi/

Regarding the apportionment of cost of pkg, don't apportion. Just make sure that when you do calculations on it, you do it at the header level (distinct counts etc).

Also: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R8SaJ__UMHI

Comment: Do you mean the cost of pkg can be marked as hidden and replaced with a measure like `Cost of pkg = AVERAGE(FactOrders[Cost of pkg])` ?

Comment: You could hide it if you have end users with direct access to the model and do it that way. What I meant was the granularity for that column will be wrong because you will have repeated values. Just ensure that when you reference that column, you keep this in mind and when aggregating with a sum or average you do so by iterating over the VALUES('Table'[Order]) rather than OrderLine

Comment: I'm reading your comment several times but didn't quite get the last sentence. That is - when aggregating so let's take an example of `cost of pkg` - what would be the difference of using `AVERAGE(FactOrders[Cost of pkg])` versus iterating over the `VALUES('Table'[Order])` - which I think you mean `AVERAGEX(VALUES(Table[order]), 'cost of pkg')` or should I use `SUMX(VALUES(Table[order]), 'cost of pkg')`?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Choose SUMX or AVERAGEX depending on your requirements but the point is that the variable you pass as the table argument will dictate the granularity. e.g. if you SUMX(VALUES(FactOrders[Cost of pkg]),[Cost of pkg] ), it will not count the duplicates which exist in the fact table. This means that there is no downside to the advice of having a single fact table like the Italians advise.

Comment: I'm testing `SUMX(VALUES(FactOrders[Cost of pkg]),[Cost of pkg] )`. The problem I'm facing is that - VALUES returns the distinct list of `cost of pkg`, and then SUMX sums it up. Isn't this incorrect? Why would I need sum of distinct values? Can you recheck this please. Maybe I need to use summarize? So, `SUMX(SUMMARIZE(FactOrders, [Cost of pkg]), [Cost of pkg])`

Comment: Sorry - that is my mistake. It should be SUMX(VALUES(FactOrders[Order Num]),[Cost of pkg] )

Comment: I can't use the column name in expression (parameter 2). Shall I write SUM or MAX I think should be fine (for parameter 2 I mean)? I tried this SUM/MAX doesn't work correctly (gives wrong values).

Comment: It needs a table name before it. 'FactOrders'[Cost of pkg]

Comment: The parameter 2 must be an expression as per the documentation. So it doesn't allow me to use a column name in parameter 2 of SUMX. This works fine: `SUMX(SUMMARIZE(FactOrders, [Cost of pkg]), [Cost of pkg])` - but is there a better approach.

Comment: Let me test as it is hard to write code without a full model

Comment: Wait - I think we need to back up or I have misunderstood. In a table visual, if you place 'FactOrders'[Order Num] as the only column, to get the cost of pkg as second column in the visual, you just need a measure as follows don't you: Measure = MINX('FactOrders', 'FactOrders'[Cost of pkg]). i.e. the context is given by the table visual?

Comment: And to get a full total, this will work:
Measure = SUMX(VALUES('FactOrders'[Order Num]), CALCULATE(MIN('FactOrders'[Cost of pkg])))

Comment: That works on my small prototype

Comment: Yes this works with the above formula you have suggested. I'll spend some time learning on why this worked. Marking this as answer. Adding CALCULATE did the trick of converting it into an expression I suppose.

Comment: CALCULATE converts your row context into a filter context via context transition

Comment: Ah so using MIN without CALCULATE wouldn't have restricted it to that row only. Absolutely understand this now and I had read about this concept, and my pleasure to use this practically for the first time in this manner.

Comment: I am faced with a problem. When I create a table visual with column1 as OrdNum, column2 as product, and column3 as the above measure, then the measure is showing the Order level value. Is this expected and any way to handle this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256362/discussion-between-variable-and-davide-bacci).