# How to model Header/Detail in Star Schema where there are measures at both granularities, whilst preserving drill-through?

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, data-modeling

My facts are Tickets (1m rows) and Ticket Actions (0.6m rows), with various dimensions (showing 2 here for simplicity) - some common to both, some unique, e.g. Action Type relates only to Ticket Actions, but it is of interest to see the Ticket Type of the Ticket 'parent' of a Ticket Action.

I have requirements for measures at both Ticket and TicketAction granularity, mainly using date fields; e.g. Tickets open at a given date, TicketActions overdue.

I also need to allow users to drill from Tickets to TicketActions and allow for table visualisations that list Tickets and TicketActions.

I have modelled the data with separate fact tables, using a bridge table to allow drill-through from Tickets to Actions:

[image]

My question is:

Should I transform this into a Star Schema? i.e. flatten Tickets and TicketActions, duplicating the date fields in Tickets. Or continue with the bridge table. Or create 2 star schemas with dimensions for each. Or another way..

Comment: What is your 1 question? PS It is unhelpful & unclear to ask 'A or B' when A & B are not mutually exclusive and/or not the only options. (And you may think they are when they are not.) Ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question.
 [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) An ERD is an image of DDL--text.

Comment: [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3579079/3404097)
[How do you effectively model inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/190296/3404097) [How much research effort?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts. But one must pin down & write many clear, concise & precise phrasings of one's question/problem/goal to search reasonably. [Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461) There's no 1 "better". What is yours & how are you stuck evaluating it?

Comment: I am not sure how else to show the relationships between the tables outside of an image. I looked at the database posts you linked but I am not sure they're relevant - this isn't a database.

Comment: It is trivial to give the text, box, line etc content of the diagram. (And nevertheless typically the GUI tool will write it for you.) For a DB design such text is called DDL. Whether the diagram describes a DB & whether it is actually an ERD or other DB design diagram that commonly but wrongly is called an ERD or a PowerBI description of a query or anything else is irrelevant. Give what can be given via text (especially, text) in text. A diagram says something. Say what it says.

Answer (score 1):

Very difficult to answer a question like this as we don't have domain knowledge of your data. However, the relationship between DIM_Tickets and FCT_Tickets is one-to-one and so you effectively have FCT_Tickets related directly to FCT_TicketActions which is not a star schema. Two fact tables should never be related and this makes me suspicious that this is probably a header/detail type scenario. If that is the case, then Alberto has a great video on how to model this here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R8SaJ__UMHI

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at the video - could well be header and detail.

Comment: Let us know how you get on

Comment: I have restated my question after seeing the video and looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77690044 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77691956. I have a similar issue - I can create 
 a single fact table which will give me a star schema and drill-through but all calculations at Ticket level will need distinct type measures. I also have large table visuals that list all Tickets, so I will still need a Ticket dimension regardless I feel.  But Albert and Marco seem very certain on star schema! The other option is 2 fact ables but I have a lot of dimensions..

Comment: I'm not sure if this changes anything - the solution is a single fact table. There is nothing wrong with distinct counts in this case. Also, you don't need a separate ticket dimension as this is stored in the fact and known as a degenerate dimension.

Comment: OK. I just need to check I can list Tickets in a table visual (with a measure of tickets count, which will always be 1) and not see duplicate Ticket IDs without the separate ticket dimension